# Server configuration error cached on client computer

Tags: browser, apache-http-server, cache

I have a web site that was up and running fine. I uploaded an erroneous `.htaccess` file leading to a configuration error on the server. I removed the `.htaccess` file to fix the problem.

Now, on my development computer, where I tried to load the web site when the configuration error was present, I still get the same error `This site can't be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)` when trying to load the web site. If I try loading the web site on another device, the site works fine.

So there seems to be some sort of caching issue on my development computer. But I can't figure out where. I have cleared all browsing data from my main web browser. But it doesn't seem to be related to the browser, since each browser I try on my development computer respond with the error when trying to load the web site, even if the web site was never loaded using that browser when the configuration error was present.

Any ideas?

Comment: If that is the case, it's likely that you just can't connect to the website. Can you reach the server using alternate means from your development machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erroneous `.htaccess` file contained a permanent redirection from http to https, but https was not yet set up and gave a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. When I removed the `.htaccess` file, the redirect was remembered, since it was permanent.

In Chrome, the redirection cache can be cleared like this:

1. Type “chrome://net-internals” into the address bar and hit Enter.
2. On the right of the top red status bar, click on the down arrow ▼ to open the drop-down menu.
3. Under the “Tools” group, choose “Clear cache”.